# Omnetpp application sends multiple streams

Tags: streaming, omnet++, packet

Let's say I have a car with different sensors: several cameras, LIDAR and so on, the data from this sensors are going to be send to some host over 5G network (omnetpp + inet + simu5g). For video it is like 5000 packets 1400 bytes each, for lidar 7500 packets 1240 bytes and so on. Each flow is encoded in UDP packets.

So in omnetpp module in `handleMessage` method I have two `sentTo` calls, each is scheduled "as soon as possible", i.e., with no delay - that corresponds to the idea of multiple parallel streaming. How does omnetpp handle situations, when it needs to send two different packets at the same time from the same module to the same module (some client, which receives sensor data streams)? Does it create some inner buffer on the sender or receiver side, therefore allowing really only one packet sending per `handleMessage` call or is it wrong? I want to optimize data transmission and play with packet sizes and maybe with sending intervals, so I want to know, how omnetpp handles multiple streaming at the same time, because if it actually buffers, maybe than it makes sense to form a single package from multiple streams, each such package will consist of a certain amount of data from each stream.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here that needs to be clarified first:

1. OMNeT++ is a discrete event simulator framework. An OMNeT++ model contains modules that communicate with each other, using OMNeT++ API calls like `sendTo()` and `handleMessage()`. Any call of the `sendTo()` method just queues the provided message into the future event queue (an internal, time ordered queue). So if you send more than one packet in a single `handleMessage()` method, they will be queued in that order. The packets will be delivered one by one to the requested destination modules when the requested simulation time is reached. So you can send as many packets as you wish and those packets will be delivered one by one to the destination's `handleMessage()` method. But beware! Even if the different packets will be delivered one by one sequentially in the program's logic, they can still be delivered simultaneously considering the simulation time. There are two time concepts here: **real-time** that describes the execution order of the code and **simulation-time** which describes the time passes from the point of the simulated system. That's why, while OMNeT++ is a single threaded application that runs each events sequentially it still can simulate infinite number of parallel running systems.

BUT:

2. You are not modeling directly with OMNeT++ modules, but rather using INET Framework which is a model directly created to simulate internet protocols and networks. INET's core entity is a **node** which is something that has network interface(s) (and queues belonging to them). Transmission between nodes are properly modeled and only a single packet can travel on an ethernet line at a time. Other packets must queue in the network interface queue and wait for an opportunity to be delivered from there.

This is actually the core of the problem for Time Sensitive Networks: given a  lot of pre-defined data streams in a network, how the various packets interfere and affect each other and how they change the delay and jitter statistics of various streams at the destination, Plus, how you can configure the source and network gate scheduling to achieve some desired upper bounds on those statistics.

The INET master branch (to be released as INET 4.4) contains a lot TSN code, so I highly recommend to try to use it if you want to model in vehicle networks.

If you are not interested in the in-vehicle communication, bit rather want to stream some data over 5G, then TSN is not your interest, but you should NOT start to multiplex/demultiplex data streams at application level. The communication layers below your UDP application will fragment/defragment and queue the packets exactly how it is done in the real world. You will not gain anything by doing mux/demux at application layer.

Comment: Hi Rudi! Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I am even more confused after it though...

I use Simu5G project for modelling 5G communication - it uses both omnetpp and inet facilities. It means that the applications are inherited from `omnetpp::cSimpleModule`, however they use inet modules like `inet::UdpSocket` to implement `sendTo()` method. 

So, in-vehicle communication is not of my interest, I just have sensor streams with different rates and frame sizes that need to be received by on-board electronics (simulated as some operational delay) and sent to the MEC host.

Comment: The idea of multiplexing at the application layer originated from the fact that I'm looking from a device perspective only: I have some communication facilities, i.e., a channel config, a network state etc., the task is to have an optimal data flow between the device and MEC server. So I want to have some instruments to influence on the data flow (still from device), if there is a big latency on the receiver side or a big PLR or so. If you have suggestions, how this could be done - will be glad to hear. Of course the payload size still can't be higher than IP's MTU limit of 1428 bytes or so.